# improve appearance of dropdown

Tags: css, razor

I am using Bootstrap CSS in a ASP.NET core app.
Any tips on improving the appearance of this drop down? better spacing,  and text look better. Thanks,Peter

[image]

This is my cshtml code :

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id='dropdown' style="width:40%">
        @Html.DropDownList("drop", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Categories, "Select"))
    </div>
    <div id='calendar' style="width:65%" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

try using Bootstrap Select to improve the apperance of dropdown Menu in Bootstrap

Comment: Thanks Chandra,  I can switch to <select > control. any suggestions on improving the spacing ?